# Angular 13 ng serve with aot: true has incorrect map files

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I upgraded from Angular 9 to Angular 13 with an Ivy compiler. By default, `AOT` is not set to true. When I run `ng build` with source maps on, everything works correctly and I can set breakpoints that are hit correctly. When I run `ng serve`, the breakpoints do not line up with the code correctly. I am not sure why this is happening or how to properly debug this. I did find that if I set `AOT` to false when running `ng serve`, the breakpoints appear to be getting hit correctly. It does not seem to make sense that `AOT` maps would work for the build, but not for serve.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to keep `AOT` set to true when running `ng serve` and still have the breakpoints work correctly?

Upgraded from Angular 13.2 to 13.3 with no change.

Comment: can you try to delete the `.angular` folder ? This "hidden" folder contains some cache file that might not be resilient to a major Angular version upgrade

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I tried deleting the .angular folder, but I got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

- Update your angular.json

1. add or update the "development" configuration inside your build:configuration

```
    "build": {
      ...
      "configurations": {
        ...
        "development": {
          ...
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      }
    }
```

2. update the serve section of your application:

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-app:build:development"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "your-app:build:development"
            }
          }
        },
```

Note: you will see also your console.log() with the right file/line instead of main.js